# Disabling and enabling internet in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want to know what is the way to enable and disable internet connection in blackberry through coding.

EDIT

```
protected void disableConnection() {
    activeConn = RadioInfo.getActiveWAFs();
    if(activeConn == 0){
        activeConn = RadioInfo.getEnabledWAFs();
    }

    mystore.setContents(new Integer(activeConn));
    mystore.commit();

    Radio.deactivateWAFs(activeConn);
    Dialog.alert("Off internet");
}

protected void enableConnection() {
    if(RadioInfo.getState() == RadioInfo.STATE_ON){
        Dialog.alert("Internet on already");
    }else if(mystore.getContents() != null){
        if(Radio.activateWAFs(Integer.parseInt(mystore.getContents().toString())) == true){
            Dialog.alert("On Internet");
        }else{
            Dialog.alert("Unable to on internet");
        }
    }else{
        Dialog.alert("Unable to on internet");
    }
}
```

These are two methods which I call on turn on and turn off button click.

Comment: For checking internet is on ya Off then for this you like this CoverageInfo.isCoverageSufficient(CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked about **internet** connectivity, so I assume you are interested in more than just the Wi-Fi connection.  Calling `Radio.deactivateWAFs(RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN);` will only disable Wi-Fi.

A better implementation would probably first check which radios are on, and then turn those radios off.  When you want to turn service on again, reactivate the radios which you turned off.  Something like this:

```java
/** we record which radios are active */
private int _activeWAFs = 0;

private void getActiveWAFs() {
    _activeWAFs = RadioInfo.getActiveWAFs();
    if (_activeWAFs == 0) {
        _activeWAFs = RadioInfo.getEnabledWAFs();
    }
}

/** turn radios off if they're currently on */
private void disableAll() {
   getActiveWAFs();
   Radio.deactivateWAFs(_activeWAFs);
}

/** turn radios on, if we turned them off with disableAll() */
private void enableAll() {
   boolean success = Radio.activateWAFs(_activeWAFs) && (RadioInfo.getState() == RadioInfo.STATE_ON);
   if (!success) {
      // do something?
   }
}
```

Also, if you want notifications about the results of these operations, or external changes to the radio, you can implement [RadioStatusListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/RadioStatusListener.html):

```java
public void networkStarted(int networkId, int service) {
   if (RadioInfo.getState() == RadioInfo.STATE_ON) {
      // network ready to use!
   }
}
```

And, **yes**, this call will affect the entire device, not just internet connectivity for your app.

Comment: Hello seems working perfectly, but when I turn off net and close my application and start browser it shows "No network" which is fine but when I again go to my app and press on network button(enableAll code execute here) success variable never becomes true.Is it because of _activeWAFs variable behaviour?

Comment: Hi, I think I have resolved that thing by using PersistentObject concept, anyways thanks for your direction it helped me.

Comment: I have done this thing, but one thing need to know, when I turn off internet through my code it stops net, but when I again turn on internet through my code it just start to requesting pages but never opens any link,any idea about this?

Comment: @R.j. When you call `enableAll()` again, it won't give you a network connection **immediately**.  It takes a few seconds for the network to re-connect.  That's why I mentioned `RadioStatusListener`.  If you have your class `implement RadioStatusListener`, and implement the methods in that interface, then the device will notify you when the network is re-connected.  Until that happens, trying to open links is probably not going to work.

Comment: thing is that when I restart my simulator and open any link it opens that link everytime, but after doing off and then on from my code it never opens link just requesting, I also wait for network connectivity(as you said this will not affect immediately) but no success.

Comment: @R.j. I updated my code with the `RadioStatuListener` implementation.  Are you calling `disableAll()` and then **immediately** calling `enableAll()`, or is there a lot of time (several seconds at least) between those calls?  I seem to remember that if you try to turn the radios on while they are still being turned off, things get messed up.

Comment: @R.j., yes this will stop everything, I believe.  Autonomous GPS might still work, but nothing else.

Comment: Hi thanks I also thought so, because when I try to make one call(simulator) it shown me message that radio is off, anyways thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Radio.deactivateWAFS() will it deactivate all the wireless connection or just internet connectivity or Bluetooth connectivity.

Example: deactive WiFi connectivity.

```
Radio.deactivateWAFs(RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN);
```

Comment: Will this effect out of our application also? Right now I am using two buttons 1st will on internet and second will off internet, after off button press i again open browser but it is opening urls.
What I want is after doing off from my program, device should unable to open any link(Internet off) and after doing on, device will allow you to open links.

Comment: @R.j., see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11217650/119114).  Yes, this affects the entire device, not just your application.

Answer (score 2):

try this -

this will turn on wifi-

```
Radio.activateWAFs(RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN);
```

this will turn off the wifi-

```
Radio.deactivateWAFs(RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN);
```