# Turn off/on network programmatically

Tags: blackberry

I'm trying to get access to Network status to turn it off or on.
I have already write the code to get the status of the network using `RadioInfo` but I can't figure out how to switch them on/off. I have looked into `Radio` and `RadioInfo` APIs, but i can't find an API that allows me to control Network. Here's my code to get network status :

```
    private boolean GetRadInfo() { 
        if(RadioInfo.getState() == RadioInfo.STATE_ON)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

is there any idea how to switch OFF/ON ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling and enabling internet in blackberry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202386/disabling-and-enabling-internet-in-blackberry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved** I used `Radio.deactivateWAFs(int);`